# How to write a sql query to figure out if a value falls within a range

Tags: sql, mysql

tableA contains {id, fromPos not null, toPos}

- fromPos and toPos denotes a range of values for a particular row
- toPos is a nullable field

and has the following values

```
tableA (1, 5)     // means any position greater than or equal to 5
tableA (2, 5, 10) // means any position between 5 and 10 (inclusive)
tableA (3, 6) 
tableA (4, 7, 9)
```

- How to fetch all entries whose position is 7. It should return the id's (1,2,3,4)
- How to fetch all entries whose position is 5. It should return the id's (1,2)
- How to fetch all entries whose position is 8. It should return the id's (1,2,3,4)

Comment: you said that table(1, 5) means position greater than 5. But you also say that fetching entries with position 5 should return 1, 2. Isn't this contradictory?

Comment: it's inclusive, will change the comments

Comment: @Jonthan apologize made a mistake. corrected it

Comment: ID=1 should be selected for position 8

Comment: erhm, your descriptions and exepected ressults are still wrong I think? Isn't 7 greater than 6 (row 3)?

Comment: @nicomen: I fixed that for the OP...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a given target value, X, the query appears to be:

```
SELECT id
  FROM TableA
 WHERE fromPos <= X
   AND (toPos >= X OR toPos IS NULL);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select * 
  from tableA t
 where t.fromPos <= requested_position
   and coalesce(t.toPos, requested_position) >= requested_position
```

`Coalesce` means that `requested_position` will be put in comparison if `t.toPos` appears to be null, thus, a comparison will always yield true and you'll process only `t.fromPos <= requested_position`

Or, you may use `between` for better readability, which is the same:

```
select * 
  from tableA t
 where requested_position between t.fromPos and coalesce(t.toPos, requested_position)
```

Comment: Will work fine, but using ISNULL() or COALESCE() in the where filters on large tables is to be avoided for performance reasons http://weblogs.asp.net/stanleygu/archive/2010/02/08/solution-5-implementing-optional-parameters-in-t-sql-stored-procedures.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @position int
set @position  = 8 

select id from tablea
where @position >= fromPos
and (@position <= toPos or toPos is null)


create table tableA
(
id int not null,
fromPos int not null,
toPos int null
)

insert into dbo.tableA(id, fromPos) values (1, 5)
insert into dbo.tableA(id, fromPos, toPos) values (2, 5, 10)
insert into dbo.tableA(id, fromPos) values (3, 6)  
insert into dbo.tableA(id, fromPos, toPos) values (4, 7, 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that when there is no toPos mentioned in your example, it will be null.

```
1. Select * from tableA where fromPos <= 7 and (toPos=null or toPos >= 7)
2. Select * from tableA where fromPos <= 5 and (toPos=null or toPos >= 5)
3. Select * from tableA where fromPos <= 8 and (toPos=null or toPos >= 8)
```

Comment: You can't do 'toPos = NULL' in standard SQL: you have to use 'toPos IS NULL'.

Comment: the he can use SET ANSI_NULLS is OFF

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id
  FROM <table>
 WHERE <value> BETWEEN fromPos AND COALESCE(toPos,99999999)
```

Comment: The table was given a name, and the general solution should not break down when the searched-for value is one hundred million or larger.